# python.exe - Entry point not found (mkl_dnn_BatchNormalizationCreateBackward_v2_F32)

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm referring to this specific Python library: https://github.com/antoinecarme/pyaf

My machine comprises of Anaconda3-4.4.0 with a separate environment which runs Python 3.5 as the pyAF library requires Python 3.5 to work.

I have installed this library on my laptop using the recommended options
on the above Github page, based on the following commands:

```
pip install scipy pandas sklearn matplotlib pydot dill pathos sqlalchemy
pip install --upgrade git+git://github.com/antoinecarme/pyaf.git
```

To execute the above, I change the environment on my Github bash to run it on Python 3.5 and I observe the following installation results:

```
**Dinesh@DESKTOP-O5O752M MINGW64 ~**
$ source activate python35
(python35)

**Dinesh@DESKTOP-O5O752M MINGW64 ~**
$ pip install scipy pandas sklearn matplotlib pydot dill pathos sqlalchemy
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python3                                                                                                                                                             5\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python                                                                                                                                                             35\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: sklearn in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\pytho                                                                                                                                                             n35\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\py                                                                                                                                                             thon35\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pydot in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python3                                                                                                                                                             5\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: dill in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35                                                                                                                                                             \lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pathos in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python                                                                                                                                                             35\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\py                                                                                                                                                             thon35\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\                                                                                                                                                             python35\lib\site-packages (from scipy)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2 in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0                                                                                                                                                             \envs\python35\lib\site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\p                                                                                                                                                             ython35\lib\site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\                                                                                                                                                             python35\lib\site-packages (from sklearn)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10 in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\pyt                                                                                                                                                             hon35\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\                                                                                                                                                             python35\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=1.5.6 in c:\to                                                                                                                                                             olkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: pyreadline>=1.7.1 in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\                                                                                                                                                             envs\python35\lib\site-packages (from dill)
Requirement already satisfied: pox>=0.2.3 in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\py                                                                                                                                                             thon35\lib\site-packages (from pathos)
Requirement already satisfied: ppft>=1.6.4.7 in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs                                                                                                                                                             \python35\lib\site-packages (from pathos)
Requirement already satisfied: multiprocess>=0.70.5 in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4                                                                                                                                                             .0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages (from pathos)
(python35)


**Dinesh@DESKTOP-O5O752M MINGW64 ~**
$ pip install --upgrade git+git://github.com/antoinecarme/pyaf.git

Collecting git+git://github.com/antoinecarme/pyaf.git
  Cloning git://github.com/antoinecarme/pyaf.git to c:\users\dines\appdata\local\temp\pip-_upr_c25-build
Requirement already up-to-date: scipy in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages (from pyaf==1.0)
Collecting pandas (from pyaf==1.0)
  Using cached pandas-0.20.3-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: sklearn in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages (from pyaf==1.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: matplotlib in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages (from pyaf==1.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: pydot in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages (from pyaf==1.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: dill in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages (from pyaf==1.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: pathos in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages (from pyaf==1.0)
Collecting sqlalchemy (from pyaf==1.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.8.2 in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages (from scipy->pyaf==1.0)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2 (from pandas->pyaf==1.0)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: pytz>=2011k in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages (from pandas->pyaf==1.0)
Collecting scikit-learn (from sklearn->pyaf==1.0)
  Using cached scikit_learn-0.19.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.10 in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->pyaf==1.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: cycler>=0.10 in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->pyaf==1.0)
Collecting pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=1.5.6 (from matplotlib->pyaf==1.0)
  Using cached pyparsing-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: pyreadline>=1.7.1 in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages (from dill->pyaf==1.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: ppft>=1.6.4.7 in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages (from pathos->pyaf==1.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: pox>=0.2.3 in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages (from pathos->pyaf==1.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: multiprocess>=0.70.5 in c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages (from pathos->pyaf==1.0)
Installing collected packages: python-dateutil, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyaf, scikit-learn, pyparsing
  Found existing installation: python-dateutil 2.6.0
    Uninstalling python-dateutil-2.6.0:
      Successfully uninstalled python-dateutil-2.6.0
  Found existing installation: pandas 0.20.1
    Uninstalling pandas-0.20.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pandas-0.20.1
  Found existing installation: SQLAlchemy 1.1.9
    Uninstalling SQLAlchemy-1.1.9:
      Successfully uninstalled SQLAlchemy-1.1.9
  Found existing installation: pyaf 1.0
    Uninstalling pyaf-1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pyaf-1.0
  Running setup.py install for pyaf: started
    Running setup.py install for pyaf: finished with status 'done'
  Found existing installation: scikit-learn 0.18.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (scikit-learn) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling scikit-learn-0.18.1:
      Successfully uninstalled scikit-learn-0.18.1
  Found existing installation: pyparsing 2.1.4
    Uninstalling pyparsing-2.1.4:
      Successfully uninstalled pyparsing-2.1.4
Successfully installed pandas-0.20.3 pyaf-1.0 pyparsing-2.2.0 python-dateutil-2.6.1 scikit-learn-0.19.0 sqlalchemy-1.1.13
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(pip.main())
  File "C:\Toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 249, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "C:\Toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 252, in main
    pip_version_check(session)
  File "C:\Toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\outdated.py", line 102, in pip_version_check
    installed_version = get_installed_version("pip")
  File "C:\Toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 838, in get_installed_version
    working_set = pkg_resources.WorkingSet()
  File "C:\Toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 644, in __init__
    self.add_entry(entry)
  File "C:\Toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 700, in add_entry
    for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):
  File "C:\Toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1949, in find_eggs_in_zip
    if metadata.has_metadata('PKG-INFO'):
  File "C:\Toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1463, in has_metadata
    return self.egg_info and self._has(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))
  File "C:\Toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1823, in _has
    return zip_path in self.zipinfo or zip_path in self._index()
  File "C:\Toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1703, in zipinfo
    return self._zip_manifests.load(self.loader.archive)
  File "C:\Toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1643, in load
    mtime = os.stat(path).st_mtime
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Toolkits\\anaconda3-4.4.0\\envs\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\pyaf-1.0-py3.5.egg'
(python35)
```

With this first method, I can see that there are errors at the end of the output. Hence, I downloaded the entire pyAF package from Github on my desktop and attempted to install the library as follows:

```
**(python35) C:\Users\dines\Desktop>** cd pyaf-master

**(python35) C:\Users\dines\Desktop\pyaf-master>** python setup.py install

running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing pyaf.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to pyaf.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to pyaf.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to pyaf.egg-info\top_level.txt
package init file 'pyaf\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
package init file 'pyaf\TS\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
package init file 'pyaf\CodeGen\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
package init file 'pyaf\Bench\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
reading manifest file 'pyaf.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'pyaf.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying pyaf\ForecastEngine.py -> build\lib\pyaf
copying pyaf\HierarchicalForecastEngine.py -> build\lib\pyaf
copying pyaf\TS\Exogenous.py -> build\lib\pyaf\TS
copying pyaf\TS\Keras_Models.py -> build\lib\pyaf\TS
copying pyaf\TS\Options.py -> build\lib\pyaf\TS
copying pyaf\TS\Perf.py -> build\lib\pyaf\TS
copying pyaf\TS\Plots.py -> build\lib\pyaf\TS
copying pyaf\TS\PredictionIntervals.py -> build\lib\pyaf\TS
copying pyaf\TS\Scikit_Models.py -> build\lib\pyaf\TS
copying pyaf\TS\SignalDecomposition.py -> build\lib\pyaf\TS
copying pyaf\TS\SignalDecomposition_AR.py -> build\lib\pyaf\TS
copying pyaf\TS\SignalDecomposition_Cycle.py -> build\lib\pyaf\TS
copying pyaf\TS\SignalDecomposition_Quant.py -> build\lib\pyaf\TS
copying pyaf\TS\SignalDecomposition_Trend.py -> build\lib\pyaf\TS
copying pyaf\TS\SignalHierarchy.py -> build\lib\pyaf\TS
copying pyaf\TS\Signal_Grouping.py -> build\lib\pyaf\TS
copying pyaf\TS\Signal_Transformation.py -> build\lib\pyaf\TS
copying pyaf\TS\Time.py -> build\lib\pyaf\TS
copying pyaf\TS\TimeSeriesModel.py -> build\lib\pyaf\TS
copying pyaf\TS\Utils.py -> build\lib\pyaf\TS
copying pyaf\CodeGen\TS_CodeGenerator.py -> build\lib\pyaf\CodeGen
copying pyaf\CodeGen\TS_CodeGen_Objects.py -> build\lib\pyaf\CodeGen
copying pyaf\Bench\Artificial.py -> build\lib\pyaf\Bench
copying pyaf\Bench\download_all_stock_prices.py -> build\lib\pyaf\Bench
copying pyaf\Bench\GenericBenchmark.py -> build\lib\pyaf\Bench
copying pyaf\Bench\MComp.py -> build\lib\pyaf\Bench
copying pyaf\Bench\NN3.py -> build\lib\pyaf\Bench
copying pyaf\Bench\stocks_symbol_list.py -> build\lib\pyaf\Bench
copying pyaf\Bench\TS_datasets.py -> build\lib\pyaf\Bench
copying pyaf\Bench\YahooStocks.py -> build\lib\pyaf\Bench
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\Bench
copying build\lib\pyaf\Bench\Artificial.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\Bench
copying build\lib\pyaf\Bench\download_all_stock_prices.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\Bench
copying build\lib\pyaf\Bench\GenericBenchmark.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\Bench
copying build\lib\pyaf\Bench\MComp.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\Bench
copying build\lib\pyaf\Bench\NN3.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\Bench
copying build\lib\pyaf\Bench\stocks_symbol_list.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\Bench
copying build\lib\pyaf\Bench\TS_datasets.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\Bench
copying build\lib\pyaf\Bench\YahooStocks.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\Bench
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\CodeGen
copying build\lib\pyaf\CodeGen\TS_CodeGenerator.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\CodeGen
copying build\lib\pyaf\CodeGen\TS_CodeGen_Objects.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\CodeGen
copying build\lib\pyaf\ForecastEngine.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf
copying build\lib\pyaf\HierarchicalForecastEngine.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS
copying build\lib\pyaf\TS\Exogenous.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS
copying build\lib\pyaf\TS\Keras_Models.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS
copying build\lib\pyaf\TS\Options.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS
copying build\lib\pyaf\TS\Perf.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS
copying build\lib\pyaf\TS\Plots.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS
copying build\lib\pyaf\TS\PredictionIntervals.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS
copying build\lib\pyaf\TS\Scikit_Models.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS
copying build\lib\pyaf\TS\SignalDecomposition.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS
copying build\lib\pyaf\TS\SignalDecomposition_AR.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS
copying build\lib\pyaf\TS\SignalDecomposition_Cycle.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS
copying build\lib\pyaf\TS\SignalDecomposition_Quant.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS
copying build\lib\pyaf\TS\SignalDecomposition_Trend.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS
copying build\lib\pyaf\TS\SignalHierarchy.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS
copying build\lib\pyaf\TS\Signal_Grouping.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS
copying build\lib\pyaf\TS\Signal_Transformation.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS
copying build\lib\pyaf\TS\Time.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS
copying build\lib\pyaf\TS\TimeSeriesModel.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS
copying build\lib\pyaf\TS\Utils.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\Bench\Artificial.py to Artificial.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\Bench\download_all_stock_prices.py to download_all_stock_prices.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\Bench\GenericBenchmark.py to GenericBenchmark.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\Bench\MComp.py to MComp.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\Bench\NN3.py to NN3.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\Bench\stocks_symbol_list.py to stocks_symbol_list.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\Bench\TS_datasets.py to TS_datasets.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\Bench\YahooStocks.py to YahooStocks.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\CodeGen\TS_CodeGenerator.py to TS_CodeGenerator.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\CodeGen\TS_CodeGen_Objects.py to TS_CodeGen_Objects.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\ForecastEngine.py to ForecastEngine.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\HierarchicalForecastEngine.py to HierarchicalForecastEngine.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS\Exogenous.py to Exogenous.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS\Keras_Models.py to Keras_Models.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS\Options.py to Options.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS\Perf.py to Perf.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS\Plots.py to Plots.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS\PredictionIntervals.py to PredictionIntervals.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS\Scikit_Models.py to Scikit_Models.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS\SignalDecomposition.py to SignalDecomposition.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS\SignalDecomposition_AR.py to SignalDecomposition_AR.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS\SignalDecomposition_Cycle.py to SignalDecomposition_Cycle.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS\SignalDecomposition_Quant.py to SignalDecomposition_Quant.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS\SignalDecomposition_Trend.py to SignalDecomposition_Trend.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS\SignalHierarchy.py to SignalHierarchy.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS\Signal_Grouping.py to Signal_Grouping.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS\Signal_Transformation.py to Signal_Transformation.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS\Time.py to Time.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS\TimeSeriesModel.py to TimeSeriesModel.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pyaf\TS\Utils.py to Utils.cpython-35.pyc
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying pyaf.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying pyaf.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying pyaf.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying pyaf.egg-info\requires.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying pyaf.egg-info\top_level.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist\pyaf-1.0-py3.5.egg' and adding 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' to it
removing 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' (and everything under it)
Processing pyaf-1.0-py3.5.egg
Copying pyaf-1.0-py3.5.egg to c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages
Adding pyaf 1.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\pyaf-1.0-py3.5.egg
Processing dependencies for pyaf==1.0
Searching for SQLAlchemy==1.1.13
Best match: SQLAlchemy 1.1.13
Adding SQLAlchemy 1.1.13 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages
Searching for pathos==0.2.1
Best match: pathos 0.2.1
Adding pathos 0.2.1 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages
Searching for dill==0.2.7.1
Best match: dill 0.2.7.1
Adding dill 0.2.7.1 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages
Searching for pydot==1.2.3
Best match: pydot 1.2.3
Adding pydot 1.2.3 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages
Searching for matplotlib==2.0.2
Best match: matplotlib 2.0.2
Adding matplotlib 2.0.2 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages
Searching for sklearn==0.0
Best match: sklearn 0.0
Adding sklearn 0.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages
Searching for pandas==0.20.3
Best match: pandas 0.20.3
Adding pandas 0.20.3 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages
Searching for scipy==0.19.1
Best match: scipy 0.19.1
Adding scipy 0.19.1 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages
Searching for ppft==1.6.4.7.1
Best match: ppft 1.6.4.7.1
Adding ppft 1.6.4.7.1 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages
Searching for pox==0.2.3
Best match: pox 0.2.3
Adding pox 0.2.3 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages
Searching for multiprocess==0.70.5
Best match: multiprocess 0.70.5
Adding multiprocess 0.70.5 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages
Searching for pyreadline==2.1
Best match: pyreadline 2.1
Adding pyreadline 2.1 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages
Searching for pyparsing==2.2.0
Best match: pyparsing 2.2.0
Adding pyparsing 2.2.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages
Searching for cycler==0.10.0
Best match: cycler 0.10.0
Adding cycler 0.10.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages
Searching for pytz==2017.2
Best match: pytz 2017.2
Adding pytz 2017.2 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages
Searching for python-dateutil==2.6.1
Best match: python-dateutil 2.6.1
Adding python-dateutil 2.6.1 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages
Searching for six==1.10.0
Best match: six 1.10.0
Adding six 1.10.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages
Searching for numpy==1.13.1+mkl
Best match: numpy 1.13.1+mkl
Adding numpy 1.13.1+mkl to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages
Searching for scikit-learn==0.19.0
Best match: scikit-learn 0.19.0
Adding scikit-learn 0.19.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using c:\toolkits\anaconda3-4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages
Finished processing dependencies for pyaf==1.0

(python35) C:\Users\dines\Desktop\pyaf-master>
```

I think the pyAF library has been installed successfully. Now, I try running by importing it on Jupyter with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

csvfile_link = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antoinecarme/TimeSeriesData/master/ozone-la.csv"
ozone_dataframe = pd.read_csv(csvfile_link);

import datetime
ozone_dataframe['Month'] = ozone_dataframe['Month'].apply(lambda x : datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m"))
ozone_dataframe.head()

%matplotlib inline  
ozone_dataframe.plot.line('Month', ['Ozone'], grid = True, figsize=(12, 8))
```

Then, when I import the following library:

```
import pyaf.ForecastEngine as autof
lEngine = autof.cForecastEngine()
lEngine.train(ozone_dataframe , 'Month' , 'Ozone', 12);
```

I get the error pop up saying:

```
The procedure entry point mkl_dnn_BatchNormalizationCreateBackward_v2_F32 
could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Toolkits\anaconda3-
4.4.0\envs\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\mkl_intel_thread.dll
```

This error pop up only dissapears when I keep clicking OK button 3 times.

Could anyone please help me on what I need to do to run this library successfully ? I'm not even aware as to what the root cause of this issue is. Please help.

---

Executing **numpy as np** and **np.show_config()**

```
(python35) C:\Users\dines>python
Python 3.5.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May 15 2017, 10:43:23) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.show_config()
lapack_mkl_info:
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2017/windows/mkl/include']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2017/windows/mkl/lib/intel64_win']
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_rt']
blas_mkl_info:
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2017/windows/mkl/include']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2017/windows/mkl/lib/intel64_win']
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_rt']
blas_opt_info:
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2017/windows/mkl/include']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2017/windows/mkl/lib/intel64_win']
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_rt']
lapack_opt_info:
    include_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2017/windows/mkl/include']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    library_dirs = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2017/windows/mkl/lib/intel64_win']
    libraries = ['mkl_lapack95_lp64', 'mkl_blas95_lp64', 'mkl_rt']
>>>
```

Comment: If you run the following, `import numpy as np` and `np.show_config()`, what results do you get?

Comment: @neurite, please see the edited post (bottom) for the results.Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the update. The linear algebra libraries on my Mac points to a folder of of conda installation, `/Users/neurite/Applications/miniconda3/envs/temp/lib`. Just a quick guess, would it make a difference if you install numpy and scipy using `conda install` (vs `pip install`) in the activated conda environment? It looks like an incompatible MKL library. Also check out this link: https://docs.continuum.io/mkl-optimizations/

Comment: Okay thanks for the reply, just a question. Should I uninstall previously installed numpy and scipy before attempting a conda install? Btw, Anaconda comes preinstalled with numpy and scipy - I guess. Any special methods to uninstall them?

Comment: It might be a lot easier to try in a new conda environment. You will need to explicitly install numpy in any conda environment using `conda install numpy`. Don't think it comes preinstalled. My general recommendation is to try to install any package needed via `conda install`. Only use `pip install` for those few packages not in conda. Let me know if this solves your problem. If it does, I'll expand it into an answer.

Comment: @neurite, I have finally solved the issue! Thank you to you. It was a long tiring process to get to this point and I couldn't have done it without you. The summary and lesson for everyone else - please install NUMPY using "conda install numpy" - Don't use PIP. Please expand this to answer.

Comment: You are welcome. I was writing [this note](https://github.com/neurite/debian-setup/wiki/Scientific-Computing) and saw your problem. I though I had to answer it. Good learning experience for me too. By the way, I summarized an answer below. If you don't mind, can you accept it so that it will help other people with similar problems.

Comment: @neurite, answer accepted. Sorry I forgot to accept the answer yesterday! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Post my comments as an answer as it is a confirmed solution.)

The problem is that the locally installed MKL package not compatible with numpy. The solution is install numpy using `conda install numpy` instead of `pip install numpy`.

To find out the MKL library numpy is linked against, run the following Python script in the activated conda environment,

```
import numpy as np
np.show_config()
```

I have a working conda environment with numpy installed. Notice the results show that the MKL library is part of the conda installation which guarantees compatibility:

```
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_intel_lp64', 'mkl_intel_thread', 'mkl_core', 'iomp5', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/Users/neurite/Applications/miniconda3/envs/temp/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/Users/neurite/Applications/miniconda3/envs/temp/include']
...
```